In Cloudflare, do I need to remove my A records for all my www servers if I already configured Load Balancing?
I have configured Load balancing in Cloudflare for three servers. Should I delete or keep the "A records" of my three servers serviced by my load balancer? I'm afraid the three A records might be messing up my load weights.


After digging through Cloudflare's docs, I finally found the answer: https://developers.cloudflare.com/load-balancing/load-balancers/dns-records/
In my case, LB takes precedence over DNS since my LB is very specific with the DNS name, which is www.domain.tld.  So I don't need to change anything. DNS will be my fallback if LB is turned off.
